# Fetch all files,size,path from directories and subdirectories php

Tags: php, function, user-defined-functions

I want to fetch all the file names, size, path from all the directories and subdirectories using a function. I have already done the same using recursive function. Here is my code.

```
function scan_dir($path, $exclude){

$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$bytestotal=0;
$nbfiles=0;

$file_data = array();

$i= 0;
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite,RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $filename => $cur) {


if ($cur->isDir())
    {
        continue ;
    }

    $files = str_replace('\\','/', $filename);
     $filesize = $cur->getSize();

    $exclude = array_filter($exclude);


     $data = array('name'=>$files, 'path'=>$cur->getPath(),'size'=>$cur->getSize());
     $file_data[] = $data;  
    $i++;
    $nbfiles++;

    $bytestotal += $filesize;       
 }
  $bytestotal = $bytestotal;
  return array( 'total_files'=> $nbfiles, 'total_size' => $bytestotal, 'files'=> $file_data);
}
```

The problem is When i run my code on linux server, due to the recursive function, it runs slow. Please can i have alternate for the same so as I can get the same output but use the different function.

I want to add a ***if else*** part i.e check the server, **if** it is **linux** then **{ }**  **else { recursive function }**
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: A check for linux alone wouldn't cut it. Speed is normally because of depth/size of the tree and the underlying file-system. Perhaps you need to reduce the depth (with recursive iterator you can control the depth http://www.php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth)

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](http://php.net/glob)

```
$folder = dirname( __FILE__ ) ."./images/*";
foreach( glob( './images/*.*' ) as $filename ) {
    echo $filename;
    echo $size = filesize($filename);
}
```